# Access AJAX method through JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Here is my `sendMessage` function:

```
sendMessage:function(message) 
       {
        var that = this;
        $.ajax({
              url: '/ajax/add_msg.php',
              method:'post',
              data: {msg: message},
       success: function(data) {
              $('#myTextArea').val('');
              that.getMessages();
                            }
             });
       }
```

I am trying to call this page but it doesn't work.

```
   <?php
     alert("reached to the add_messages");
     session_start();
  if (isset($_POST['msg'])) 
     {
         require_once __DIR__ . '/../../core/FbChatMock.php';
         $userId = (int) $_SESSION['user_id'];       
         // Escape the message string
         $msg = htmlentities($_POST['msg'],  ENT_NOQUOTES);
         $chat = new FbChatMock();
         $result = $chat->addMessage($userId, $msg);
      }
   ?>
```

The path is correct.

Comment: Do you get some errors at console ? Anything ? Does the request comes to file? More details needed..

Comment: does it get inside your js function? do a console.log('test') before "var that = this;" in the sendMessage and see if it prints 'test' to the console

Comment: alert("reached to the add_messages"); ... are you sure ? seems you are using javascript in PHP

Comment: `alert`? php has no `alert` function, unless you defined it.

Comment: he could create `function alert($string) { /** asd **/ }` we don't know :D, but there were no includes at file so i guess it was 500 Internal Error...

Comment: i used alert for notification but it dnst work . chat.js:28 POST http://localhost:8080/ajax/add_msg.php 404 (Not Found)
send @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4
sendMessage @ chat.js:28
PushMessage @ bomlist.php:233
onkeypress @ bomlist.php:1 this is the error

Comment: localhost:8080/ajax/add_msg.php 404 (Not Found) means the path is wrong. Or is the filename.

Comment: As @MarcinPewiński said check your path or filename, and also remove from php line `alert("")`.. and it should work.. (for php output, you can use `echo "My string";`)

Answer (score 0):

As you said you receive 404 (Not found) for POST localhost:8080/ajax/add_msg.php

You should check is your folder `ajax` located at the very begin of `www` directory or it has some folders to get to `ajax`. And then is your `filename` -> `add_msg.php` correct, or you missed something.

After that from PHP remove the line with `alert("...");` it will cause 500 Internal Error, because PHP has no `alert` function except you were created the same, but as no includes to any php file before i guess you didn't created it...

And for outputing in PHP you can use `echo "I came to add_msg.php!";`

Best regards & happy coding..